# How to access OpenGL rendering context on Android with Delphi XE5?

Tags: android, delphi, opengl-es, delphi-xe5

How to create OpenGL rendering context on Android device when developing an application with Delphi XE5?

Basically I don't know where to start. There are no OpenGL examples yet.

What I would expect to exist:

- Some kind of event (Panel.OnRender) that would provide an existing context in which I could call OpenGL calls.
- Generic TOpenGLSurface control that could be placed in forms designer
- A way to create context on main form in runtime.

From my research so far I that `TWindowManager.Render` has access to OpenGL calls and uses them to render popup windows.

**EDIT:** Adding a Timer to a form and calling this procedure fills the screen with green, so that means GL context is already there:

```
procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  glClearColor(0, 1, 0, 0);
  glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT or GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT or GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
  eglSwapBuffers(TCustomAndroidContext.SharedDisplay, TCustomAndroidContext.SharedSurface);
end;
```

The question is - how to properly handle it, cos rendering on Timer in controlled environment is definitely a bad idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to append to this answer as new details reveal.

**Attempt 1**

Adding a Timer to a form and calling this procedure fills the screen with green, so that means GL context is already there:

```
procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  glClearColor(0, 1, 0, 0);
  glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT or GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT or GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
  eglSwapBuffers(TCustomAndroidContext.SharedDisplay, TCustomAndroidContext.SharedSurface);
end;
```

Of course rendering on Timer in controlled environment is definitely a bad idea. The app kept on flickering on minimize/maximize.

---

**Attempt 2**

I have overridden `TContextAndroid` class (made a copy of Delphi unit and placed it into my app folder). I was able to inject custom code into `DoEndScene` method and it has successfully executed it - for this test just a simple `glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);`. This has filled the entire application area with color. This time the application did not flickered and behaved just like normal.

---

**Attempt 3**

Here's the code that made it to work and that does not looks hacky:

```
types
  TMyForm = class(TForm3D)
    procedure Form3DRender(Sender: TObject; Context: TContext3D);
  end;

implementation

//Event handler for TForm.OnRender
procedure TMyForm.Form3DRender(Sender: TObject; Context: TContext3D);
begin
  glClearColor(1, 1, 0, 1);
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
end;
```

Comment: You need to use the units FMX.Types3D, Androidapi.Gles; Other possible useful ones: FMX.Platform.Android, Androidapi.Gles2, Androidapi.JNI.OpenGL;